# In-place shift operation in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I save the shift operation in pandas to a same column, the below line returns the new shifted column.

```
 df.groupby('uid')['top'].shift(periods=2)
```

I want to apply the shift operation on `top` column itself. Is there any way I can do in-place shift operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not exist `inplace` method [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), need assign back to same column:

```
df['top'] = df.groupby('uid')['top'].shift(periods=2)
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(top = df.groupby('uid')['top'].shift(periods=2))
```

---

Also I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: I am thinking of more faster way of doing this, can you please advice - doing this way is more faster than converting it to numpy array and then use shift in numpy would be faster? After shift I will insert back to `df` from numpy

Comment: @ajayramesh - hmmm, `groupby.shift` is not implemented in numpy, so solution in numpy if possible, but not easy.